# How to connect to TMDB api

Tags: java, api, themoviedb-api

Here is my api key: 7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99

And I am trying to connect to TMDB api: here is my code:

```
package movieDBapiconnnection;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class connection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            URL url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99/3/movie/550");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
    }
}
```

But it always showing me the error that:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99/3/movie/550
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at movieDBapiconnnection.connection.main(connection.java:17)

Comment: "Here is my api key: blech" Why would you *ever* give out your API key? You may as well hand out free copies of your house keys and passwords.

Comment: @hexafraction it doesn't matter for me, the problem is the connection issue, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would use a TMDB wrapper.  Get a Java wrapper at: https://github.com/Omertron/api-themoviedb.  Use the fully tested and tried wrapper rather than trying to connect to it and creating your models from scratch.  Typically in a wrapper when you instantiate a class, you pass in the API key into the constructor and the wrapper does the rest.

Comment: Do you have any working example for this wrapper? how can I use it?

Comment: @Tamawy I don't have time to grab my code, but the documentation above shows examples of usage.

Comment: that should get you started

Answer (score 1):

Your error is simply because of extra characters in your API key parameter

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99/3/movie/550

remove the **/3/movie/550**, as this is just a typo,
so the correct one is

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99

Note:
Change **7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99** into your correct API key

Answer (score 0):

You passed the wrong URL, pass this URL
"http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99

```
URL url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=7b5e30851a9285340e78c201c4e4ab99");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to the the networking part in a background thread.
using main thread for this kind of operation will likely give you a similar error.
use an AsynchTask and doInBackground() to achieve this.